# Wallch changing frequency resets automatically

Tags: wallch

I have been using the wallpaper changing utility Wallch for quite some time and very happy with the experience.

But recently the utility has started giving some trouble.

No matter what I do, the frequency of changing the wallpapers always resets to the minimum value (10 secs) automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wallch developer here. No need to post a bug at askubuntu :D

I have changed the bug at launchpad to "Fix Commited"

Wallch 4.0 should be ready in 1-2 weeks, if you are in a hurry use our latest ppa of version 3

For 12.04:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wallch/12.04-3+
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install wallch
```

For 13.04/13.10:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wallch/3+
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install wallch
```

For instant updates (within 24 hours from the last code change):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wallch/wallch-daily
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install wallch
```

Answer (score 1):

The bug has probably been fixed in a development release.You may either chose to wait until version 4.0 is officially released on ubuntu repositories, or you can get the development release.

Read [installation instructions](http://wall-changer.sourceforge.net/downloads/installations.html) for getting the development release.

Alternately, you may choose to get the recent source code and build it.You can get the code [here](https://code.launchpad.net/~wallch/wallpaper-changer/trunk). For instructions on building source code, read [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingEasyHowTo) .